# Webhook Query and Clarification

Tags: webhooks

I am working on an application which involves writing webhooks for receiving the notifications from the other application server. I am new to webhooks concept and created sample webhook endpoint which will consume the event notifications and display. I have deployed my application on port eg: 8091 and expecting the notifications to be received on the same port. But the application server which produces the notification expects the webhook endpoint to be opened on specific ports like "8888". I want to understand if it possible to port forward the notifications from port 8888 to port 8091 as in my example.

Appreciate your help

Thanks